# c++ unit-tests sample in open-source-project

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, qtestlib

I'm interested in learning about c++-unit-testing in the 'real-world'. I'd like to see a complex class with good test-coverage. Preferably tested with g-test or qtestlib. I had a look at KDE and Chromium but didn't find what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you have a [proper knowledge of the gtest framework](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_7_Documentation), in order to fully understand the test coverage you should first understand the project's needs and how it works.

That said, clang has a good [unit tests](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/unittests) coverage and code generation tests which often use advanced mocking techniques.

There's no silver bullet to your question since it's based on your personal experience and preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [searching on github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22gtest.h%22&type=Code&ref=searchresults) for gtest usage, and choosing an domain you could easily understand.

Answer (score 0):

[Modern C++ Programming with Test-Driven Development](https://pragprog.com/book/lotdd/modern-c-programming-with-test-driven-development) by Jeff Langr is a a great book for unit testing with C++ and gtest. It has lots of examples and good style.